Why isn't my computer flooded with Beacon frames?
I used Wireshark to capture IEEE 802.11 Beacon frames in promiscuous mode. I see frames from about a dozen of AP's around me.
But I receive them only once in a few seconds, despite AP's having beacon intervals in range 25-100 ms. And in fact, the majority of the frames are from the AP I'm connected to.
Shouldn't I be seeing dozens of Beacon frames every second?
